# Context in React with typescript is not behaving as expectad. What do I miss?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I recently started to use Typescript and it seems like I am still missing some things. I made a login authentication, that works without any problems in normal javascript. When I attempted to bring it over to Typescript, it is not working at all.
The problem is, that it is using the properties defined in the initialization of the context. Instead I want to overwrite them in my context provider.

Here is my code.

```
// typedefs
type Token = {
    id: string;
    iat: number;
    exp: number;
}

type User = {
    username?: string;
    id?: string;
}

type Auth = {
    user: User | null;
    login: (username: string, token: string, id: string) => any;
    logout: () => any;
}

type AuthAction = {
    type: string;
    payload: User | null;
}


let userToValidate: User = {username: '', id: ''};
if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    if(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')){
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode<Token>(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') as string);
        if(decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()){
            localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
        }
        else {
            const {data} = useQuery(FIND_USER, {variables: {id : decodedToken.id}});
            userToValidate.id = decodedToken.id;
            userToValidate.username = data.user.username;
        }
    }
}

let initialState: Auth = {
    user: userToValidate,
    login: (username: string, token: string, id: string) => {
    },
    logout: () => {
    }
}

const authReducer = (state: Auth = initialState, action: AuthAction) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN:
            return{
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case LOGOUT:
            return{
                ...state,
                user: null
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const AuthContext = createContext<{state: typeof initialState}>({state: initialState});
const AuthProvider: React.FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {

    initialState = {
        user: userToValidate,
        login: (username: string, token: string, id: string) => { console.log('called');
            if(token){
                localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
            }
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN,
                payload: {username, id}
            });
        },
        logout: () => {
            localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
        }
    }


    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value = {{state}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { AuthProvider, AuthContext }
```

Super thankful for any hint :)

Comment: Why do you set `initalState`, then pass that to `createContext`, then in `AuthProvider` set a new `initialState` and pass that to `createReducer`? Not sure exactly what's going on here, but you probably should have `const initialState` and not change it. Ever. Lastly, according to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that default value is only used when the provider is _not_ a parent. So if you are getting the default value, then perhaps `AuthProvder` is not actually a parent for that component somehow?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot!! The code works, it was really the child parent relation. I had to wrap the login logic in its own component again before rendering as a child of the provider! I know that it is suboptimal to redefine the context. I have to do this however to dispatch the state in teh function I pass down in the provider. If there is any more elegant way to achieve this, I am more than happy to implement it :)